# Rotate CGPDFDocument/Page

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cgpdfdocument

I'm loading a CGPDFDocument, adding that as a sublayer to a UIView (myContentView), and then adding myContentView to a UIScrollView.  That works fine.  Now I want to allow the user to rotate the PDF if they choose to.  It's easy to get the PDF to initially display with some rotation- I just do it here:

```
- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx {
    CGContextSaveGState (ctx);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(ctx));
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0.0, layer.bounds.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(myPageRef, kCGPDFCropBox, layer.bounds, rotation, true));
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(ctx, myPageRef);
    CGContextRestoreGState (ctx);
}
```

But, how can I do it after the initial load?

Note: I've tried just rotating myContentView, which seems like it works, but after doing it, I can no longer zoom/unzoom the PDF... I think what I need is to force drawLayer to be called again with a new value in "rotation"... how do I do that?

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 0):

To signal that the layer needs to be redrawn, send it a `setNeedsDisplay` or `setNeedsDisplayInRect:` message. You have to store the desired rotation angle in an ivar/property and access that value from `drawLayer:inContext:`.

Comment: Still nothing.  I've tried a few ways: saving a ref to the CATiledLayer as an ivar, then calling setNeedsDisplay on that.. also tried accessing the CALayer through scrollView.subviews[0].sublayers[0] and calling setNeedsDisplay on that.. neither have worked.  I am storing rotation as an ivar so it updates properly each time.  Breakpoints set in drawLayer aren't called.

Comment: Based on some Googling, I'm beginning to suspect this my be an iOS SDK 4.x bug.

Answer (score 0):

try calling setNeedsDisplay on your layer